# Python Regex blocking pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm working with Python 3.x and re module.

I have some strings from filenames that I would like to discriminate.
My strings look like this :
output_XXXX.txt
where

- XXXX has a variable length,
- can have any alphanumeric character (lower and uppercase)
- can have "." "_" or "-"

For the moment I got this : `"\Aoutput_[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*[.]*\.txt\Z"`
But I miss something because (according to my pattern modifications)

- I stopped at the first . in the string,
- or I have to get no . in it,
- or it stops before .txt

What is the info I'm missing to complete the regex ?

NB : of course I can work with endswith function, and check the beginning to extract only the body of my string but I want to understand what I miss to fully work with regex.

Thank you

Comment: Add `.` to `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` to allow that character.

Comment: BTW, you can use `\w` as a shortcut for `a-zA-Z0-9_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `[.]*` means matching 0+ times a dot, but if there is another char in the string after the dot and then again a dot it will not match.

You could add add a mere dot to the character class, but note that it could possibly also allow filenames like `output_........txt`

You can also use an optionally repeating group matching a dot followed by 1+ times any of the characters in the character class if you don't want to allow matching consecutive dots.

```
\Aoutput_[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)*\.txt\Z
```

- `\A` Start of string
- `output_[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*`
- `(?:` Non capture group ( to repeat as a whole)

  - `\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+ Match a` .` and 1+ times any of the listed chars
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat
- `\.txt` Match `.txt`
- `\Z` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/45HdoT/1)

If you don't want to match consecutive dots or hyphens:

```
\Aoutput_\w*(?:[.-]\w+)*\.txt\Z
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vffK4i/1/)

Comment: Thank you ! It's quite difficult to understand, for example why duplicating the Alphanumeric pattern, but it will help me for sure to understand better and continues on some tests !

Comment: @mike I have added an explanation for the pattern

Comment: Thank you  ! That's what I found after answering to you. You confirm what I thought :)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use:

```
^output_[A-Za-z0-9.-_]+\.txt$
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but the dot wasn't accepted inside my brackets (python gave me errors) so I tried to put it outside.
For no explanation today it's working : same computer which didn't reboot.

I wrote something bad I think. Thx